# How to navigate among files in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, navigation

I have several Ada files belonging to a project. Specification are in .ads files, code in .adb files, etc. The point is that I would like to "jump" from a function in a file to the declaration of that function, or from a variable to the definition of its type, etc. Which config should I implement in Emacs?

Answer (score 0):

`C-h r` to visit the Emacs manual, then `i tag TAB`. That lists pages (nodes) of the Emacs manual that have to do with tags.

Choose `find-tag`, for example, which takes you to node [Find Tag](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Tag.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not a straight-forward question in Emacs. The problem is, emacs has multiple bits of functionality which can assist in this regard, which makes it difficult to provide concrete examples. However, here are some things you probably want to look at using google and emacs info pages

- Ada mode. I'm not an ada programmer, but I would start with this mode. Get it configured and working first.
- Projectile is a vary popular emacs package for working with projects. Makes navigating around in project files vary easy
- Tags. The 'original' way to maintain an 'index' of tags refeencing various file locations/definitions, making it easy to jump around. Make sure to check out the linux 'global' tags support, which is a little better than older traditional emacs ctags.
- imenu. A handy built-in emacs feature which can be used to provide dynamic menu like functionality. It can be setup to use tag files (as well as other approaches) and could provide much of what you want.
- Speedbar. Provides a useful file and tag display window which can be useful when you need to jump around.

Don't forget to look in the package archives - make sure you have added at least the melpa archive and look for ada related packages.

The key thing is to build up your configuraiton slowly and try really hard to do it yourself. Feel free to borrow examples and bits of code from whatever repository and on-line examples you can find, but try to make sure you understand what it does. The learning curve is steep to start with, but will level of pretty quickly if you stick at it. Try to avoid the temptation to just cut and paste bits of code you don't understand - you will almost certainly end up with conflicts and if you don't understand the code, you won't be able to fix it.

One of the key benefits of emacs is that you can make it use the workflow you want rather than being forced to learn some arbitrary workflow imposed by the editor or designers of the editor. This is great, but it can take some time to tweak things and get them to where you want. The time is worth it.